# Is there any way to import database directly without using seeding and migration in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

i have a import database file called **database.sql** and i placed that file into my laravel application **"database/xyz"** directory. i want when my application run first time, all data inserted to connected database.

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to import that file into a DBMS first (ex: mysql, postgres). The same one you used to create the dump file.

Answer (score 1):

You can always run a custom statement in your Laravel application with

```
DB::statement(" <query here> ");
```

If your query (or queries, database dumps usually are just a series of queries) lives in a .sql file, there's nothing wrong with reading it from the file. Something like this

```
DB::statement( file_get_contents('/path/to/your/database.sql') );
```

Altough your titles says you want to avoid migrations (I assume you basically just want to avoid the schema builder), I still recommend putting this in a migration file, since they exist for exactly that purpose. Also Laravels artisan will make sure that a migration is only run once, so you don't have to handle that yourself.

A simple command will do the job:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Thanks Fitzi. But migration and seeding takes much time. Is there any way to reduce migration and seeding time.

Comment: @DeepakSharma In my experience it usually takes no more than a few seconds. It does depend of course on how your integrations look like. The more you have, the longer it takes. It also depends on your seeding. Do you seed lots of data or do you have expensive operations going? On the other hand, even if it takes a few minutes, it may not be too bad because you usually do this only once in your applications lifecycle.

Comment: Download the package iSeed, it lets you create database seeds from your existing database. It's really fast and simple, and all you have to do is run php artisan migrate --seed to seed the database. Download it here https://github.com/orangehill/iseed